# How to find the frequency of words in a list created from a .csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, word-frequency

I am trying to write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the file using the csv.reader() method. The file contains a list of words separated by commas. The program should output the words and their frequencies (the number of times each word appears in the file) without any duplicates.

The file *input1.csv* has **hello,cat,man,hey,dog,boy,Hello,man,cat,woman,dog,Cat,hey,boy**

So far I have this:

```
import csv
with open('input1.csv', 'r') as wordsfile:
words_reader = csv.reader(wordsfile)
for row in words_reader:
    for word in row:
        count = row.count(word)
        print(word, count)
```

But my output is this:
"hello 1
cat 2
man 2
hey 2
dog 2
boy 2
Hello 1
man 2
cat 2
woman 1
dog 2
Cat 1
hey 2
boy 2"

I am trying to output this but without any duplicates, I'm stumped and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you printed `row` and `word` in the loops did you see what you expected? If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: @wwii Im gonna be honest, I didnt understand anything you just said. Im just a beginner at this and this was something we just learned in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using set()

```
import csv
with open('input1.csv', 'r') as wordsfile:
words_reader = csv.reader(wordsfile)
for row in words_reader:
    list_of_words = set(row)
    for word in list_of_words:
        count = row.count(word)
        print(word, count)
```

I am not very familiar with csv library and I dont know if row is a list or not so sorry if this throws an error.
If row is a string probably you can use

```
row = row.split()
list_of_words = set(row)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your comment but I'm new here, and too low rep. You were right .csv is a list. What does `set()` do and how does it work? It seems that the command is random, is there a way to make it so that its that hen I put it in its in order?

Comment: set() creates a set from the list, so it removes all words that are repeating.
to remove randomness you could use list_of_words = list(set(row))

Answer (score 3):

```py
import csv

input1 = input()

with open(input1, 'r') as wordsfile:
    words_reader = csv.reader(wordsfile)
    for row in words_reader:
        list_of_words = row

no_duplicates_in_list = list(dict.fromkeys(list_of_words))
listlength = len(no_duplicates_in_list)

for i in range(listlength):
    print(no_duplicates_in_list[i], list_of_words.count(no_duplicates_in_list[i]))
```

pretty much the same as Aryman's but the order is the same as in the csv

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I'm pretty basic with Python but I was able to figure this out in about an hour of trying different for loops etc. I ended up sticking to using lists as that is what the assignment indicated in the instructions. In order to get rid of the duplicates within the first list, I made a second list and nested an if statement that only adds words that aren't contained within it, resulting in a new list of one copy of each word from the first.

```
filename = input()
words = []
new_words = []
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        for word in row:
            words.append(word)
        for word in words:
            freq = words.count(word)
            if word not in new_words:
                new_words.append(word)
                print(word, freq)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv

name = input()
with open(name, 'r') as myfile:
    Reader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
    dictionary = dict()
    for l in Reader:
        for m in l:
            if m in dictionary:
                dictionary[m] = dictionary[m] + 1
            else:
                dictionary[m] = 1
    for n in list(dictionary.keys()):
        print("{} {}".format(n, dictionary[n]))
```

Answer (score -1):

import csv
words = {}
user_file = input()
with open(user_file, "r") as csvfile:
inputreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in inputreader:
listofwords = row

```
    for i in row:
        if i in words:
            words[i] += 1
        else:
             words[i] = 1
```

for i in words:
print(i, words[i])

Comment: This helped me get the word's frequency. I hope that helps. I was able to create a dict out of the words and their frequency, then print those keys and their values for the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).